# Web Client Application receives a "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, weblogic12c

I managed to configure HTTPS on my weblogic on a remote server successfully by creating a custom certificate.

Over at the client side (a different computer from the one running the weblogic), I installed the server certificate using the InstallCert.java resource file I got off the internet. I copied the jssecacerts file into my **JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/** folder and I wrote a simple JAX-WS standalone application to test it:

```
URL url = new URL("https://IP:Port/app/service?wsdl");
QName qname = new QName("http://service.org/", "queryservice");

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> hostname.equals(IP));

Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
QueryService port = service.getPort(QueryService.class);
```

And it worked! Great. Wonderful. So I implemented the same thing on my web application, deployed it on the weblogic server on my laptop, and I tried to access the same webservice, the same way as my standalone app, and I keep getting a **sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
   unable to find valid certification path to requested target** exception.

I've checked several tutorials and they keep saying the same thing: once I put the jssecacerts file in **JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/** everything should be fine.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Turns out, the weblogic client server only sees cacerts in the JRE as the recognised keystore, and not jssecacerts. I had to export the server certificate from jssecacerts and import it into cacerts - an important step I missed out.

These are the steps:

1. After getting the InstallCert.java file from here: https://github.com/escline/InstallCert, run **java InstallCert [host]:[port]** (Enter the given list number of the certificate you want to add in the list when you run the command - likely just 1)
2. Run the command, keytool -exportcert -alias [host]-1 -keystore jssecacerts -storepass changeit -file [host].cer
3. Then run this command: keytool -importcert -alias [host] -keystore
   [path to system keystore] -storepass changeit -file [host].cer

Afterwards, you should be fine. Your system keystore should be cacerts.